# Looping problem in C, Program Execute Without Input

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am writing a simple program in C but I have a problem. As you see from the code below, I have only one while loop but the program execute after certain choices without we select.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>


double area_of_triangle(double, double, double);

int main(){
    SetConsoleTitle("Calculate Triangle Area");

    char pilihan;
    double a, b, c, area2;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t1. Triangle Area\n");
        printf("\t2. Out");

        printf("\n\nSelect your choice:");
        scanf("%c", &pilihan);

        switch(pilihan){
        case '1':
            printf("\t\t\tFind The Area Of A Triangle\n");
            printf("\tArea Of A Triangle:\n\n");
            printf("\tFirst:");
            scanf("%lf", &a);
            printf("\tSecond:");
            scanf("%lf", &b);
            printf("\tThird:");
            scanf("%lf", &c);

            area2 = area_of_triangle(a, b, c);
            printf("\n\n\tTriangle Area = %.2lf\n\n", area2);
            break;
        case '2':
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tINVALID!!! 1 OR 2 ONLY\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

double area_of_triangle(double a, double b, double c){

  double s, area2;

  s = (a+b+c)/2;

  area2 = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));

  return area2;
}
```

This is the output:

```
        1. Triangle Area
        2. Out

Select your choice:1
                        Find The Area Of A Triangle
        Area Of A Triangle:

        First:423
        Second:423
        Third:423


        Triangle Area = 77478.53



        1. Triangle Area
        2. Out

Select your choice:

                        INVALID!!! 1 OR 2 ONLY


        1. Triangle Area
        2. Out

Select your choice:
```

As you saw, the program executed and choose default value itself which is `INVALID!!! 1 OR 2 ONLY` without any input and press enter. I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `scanf()` to read characters, it leaves the newline character in the buffer, so the next time `scanf()` is encountered, it consumes the newline character and leaves you with the invalid results you're getting.

To avoid this problem, you can format `scanf()` to consume the newline, like this:

```
        printf("\n\nSelect your choice:");
        scanf("%c\n", &pilihan);
```